Как отключить popup blocker?
Как отключить popup blocker для microsoft edge?

Я думаю, если вы вбили бы этот запрос в Google, то сразу же бы увидели ответ. Если вас там забанили, то надо зайти в настройки Edge и ввести в поиск pop-up. В Pop-ups and redirects разрешить.
